# Overriding a system function by using -wrap in mingw

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

For testautomation purposes, we want to override the `time` function, which is scattered across the code.

For this purpose, we are using the mingw (gcc) linker flag `-Wl,--wrap=time`, which allowed us to redirect calls to the system `time` function to a custom module, where we manipulated the time to match the acceleration of the automation.

For Windows, we also had to wrap around _time32, because mingw performs an inline forwarding from `time` to (the windows function) `_time32`.

This worked just fine, as long as we used the Mingw version 7.3.0 (32 bit). But after switching to Mingw 11.2.0 (64 bits) it just...stopped working.

We already tried wrapping around _time64 instead of _time32, but the wrap just doesn't happen.

When forward declaring the 'time' function manually, (`extern "C" time_t time(time_t *);`) the wrap works flawlessly, but the entire purpose of using `wrap` is to avoid having to change the entire source code.

I can see how/why it fails to wrap around `time` (the function being `static __inline` within the header and therefor 'defined' whenever the header is included), but `_CRTIMP __time64_t __cdecl _time64(__time64_t *_Time);` should be plenty 'undefined reference' for wrap to work.

Any ideas on how I could proceed in this matter?

The linker script I am currently working with:

```
TARGET = Sandbox
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG  *= console
CONFIG  -= qt app_bundle

SOURCES += main.cpp \ #MainWindow.cpp
    SecondFile.c

QMAKE_CFLAGS        += -fsigned-char
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS      += -fsigned-char
QMAKE_LFLAGS        += -Wl,--wrap=__time64 -Wl,--wrap=time
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

extern "C" {
    //time_t time(time_t *);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    time_t timestamp;
    time(&timestamp);
    printf("%lu\n", timestamp);
    return 0;
}
```

SecondFile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

time_t __wrap_time(time_t *p)
{
    if (p)
        *p = 1;
    return 1;
}

time_t __wrap__time32(time_t *p)
{
    return __wrap_time(p);
}

time_t __wrap__time64(time_t *p)
{
    return __wrap_time(p);
}
```

I'd like to note, that `time_t` is an architecture dependent typedef, so `time_t` is `__time64_t` in the context of this test.

Edit:
After doing a little more digging, and running `nm` on the .o file, I got this output:

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_frame
0000000000000000 N .debug_frame$_Z6printfPKcz
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 N .debug_rnglists
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_Z6printfPKcz
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 t .text$_Z6printfPKcz
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_Z6printfPKcz
                 U __imp___acrt_iob_func
                 U __imp__time64
                 U __main
                 U __mingw_vfprintf
0000000000000000 T _Z6printfPKcz
000000000000001f T main
0000000000000000 t time
```

This suggests, that whilst the preprocessor does not touch the call (I checked), the linker translates it to something entirely different.

However when trying to wrap the `__imp__` function instead, I get a segmentation fault when trying to run the code.

Comment: Possibly your `time()` is getting redefined out from under you.  If you check the preprocessed source (`g++ -E -o main.preprocessed main.cpp`) does that reveal anything interesting?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, no, the preprocessor does not alter the call. However `nm` revealed something interesting. More details in the main post in a moment.

Comment: I bet it's *the compiler* that does the translation (after preprocessing), else there's no reason why the forward declaration would have any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but the issue can be solved by 'hiding' the call to `time` using a wrapper header file.

By creating a proxy `time.h` header file (which should lodged in the include path, so `#include <time.h>` finds it), I can 'inject' my own calls.

The header file could then look like:

```
#include_next <time.h>

extern time_t __wrap_time(time_t *);
#define time(x) __wrap_time(x)
```

What this does should be rather obvious:

- `#include_next <time.h>` includes the real time.h, thereby giving you access to all the functions you aren't trying to mock.
- The forward declaration (possibly needs to be wrapped with 'extern "C"') declares the function you want to wrap.
- The macro replaces ALL calls to the function to the wrapped function (which is why you need the forward declaration).

Just adding `time(x)=__wrap_time(x)` to the compile flags does not work, because it would also replace the declaration inside `time.h`, putting you back to square one. (And you'd still need the forward declaration)

Including `<ctime>` also won't work, because within, `#undef time` is called, undoing the macro replacement you are injecting.

This approach essentially circumvents the `wrap` flag altogether. In order to still call the original time (in order to call `__real_time`), you only need to `#undef` the macro and thereby access the original function.

I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

> When forward declaring the 'time' function manually, (`extern "C" time_t time(time_t *);`) the wrap works flawlessly, but the entire purpose of using `wrap` is to avoid having to change the entire source code.

If inserting such a forward declaration on a dynamic, per-compilation basis is sufficient to resolve the issue, then `g++` (and `gcc`) can do that.  The `-include` command-line option comes to bear here.  You would create a local, supplemental header such as this:

**time_forward.h**

```
#include <time.h>
extern "C" time_t time(time_t *);
```

Then you would instruct `g++` to act as if it were `#include`d at the beginning of each translation unit like so:

```bash
$ g++ -include time_forward.h -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

Of course, for use with `qmake`, you would more likely add `-include time_forward.h` to your `QMAKE_CFLAGS` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: That's awesome and I definitely didn't know about `-include`, but I don't think it'll solve the issue, because as soon as `time.h` is included, it also has that static declaration of time and will therefor override the forward declaration. The forward declaration only works, if time.h is NOT included.

Comment: Is that a prediction, @RefugnicEternium, or an empirical observation?

Comment: A prediction based on previous observations. I have yet to actually try it.

Comment: Then it's worth testing, @RefugnicEternium.  I have reason to suspect that your compiler is being cleverer than you give it credit for. (But this is an educated guess.)

Comment: I did try it and while `-include` did do exactly what you said it would, the static declaration of `time` within `time.h` did exactly what I said it would...it overwrote my external declaration, replacing it with the call to _time64, which, for some reason, I cannot wrap.